# В IE не отображается favicon

Tags: html, internet-explorer

Во всех браузерах есть, в в ИЕ нет. вот ссыль http://bit.ly/uZeXEg

Comment: кто нибудь открывал ссылку?, может у автора закешировался каким-то образом иконка?

Comment: я открывал

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE6+

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="путь_до_иконки/favicon.ico" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon"></link>
```

или

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="путь_до_иконки/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"></link>
```

Обратите внимание, что IE позволяет использовать только .ico файлы.

Остальные браузеры

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="путь_до_иконки/favicon.ico"></link>
```

Дополнительные материалы по теме.

1. [How to Add a Shortcut Icon to a Web Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537656(v=vs.85).aspx) *msdn*
2. [How to Add a Favicon to your Site](http://www.w3.org/2005/10/howto-favicon) *w3c*
3. [Favicon](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon) *wiki*

Comment: <link href="http://oknastar.ru/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon"/>

у меня все для ИЕ сделано

Comment: Попробуйте перенести подключение в самый вверх <head>, может быть один из скриптов в нём блокирует загрузку.

Comment: Я не знаю почему у вас не отображается иконка. У меня она отображается начиная с IE6+.

Почистите кэш браузера.

Comment: С разных компом смотрел, кеш чистил. Не отображался и не отображается. Перенес в самый верх <head>

Comment: @Tchort: Мне кажется у Вас проблема не в IE и не в коде, а с самой иконкой, файл какой-то левый. Попробуйте заменить на другую или эту пересохранить из другого редактора.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте прописать полный путь к favicon (http://www.oknastar.ru/favicon.ico).

Comment: не помогло

Comment: попробуйте переместить сразу после начала head